# Fresh installation - apt-get update fails with 403 forbidden

Tags: updates, release-juno, apt

I am quite new to Linux.
After I did fresh install from iso and update system components from AppCenter([appcenter](/questions/tagged/appcenter)) I wanted to install net-tools using apt-get.

firstly I did `sudo apt-get update` but got error.
Screen from my vm (sorry cant install vmware tools because of `apt-get` problem).

[image]

Now I have searched quite a lot and found lot of tips leading to editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` but since its fresh install I think it should work OOB.

running

```
lsb_release -a
```

returns

```
Distributor id: elementary
Description: elementary OS 5.0 Juno
Release: 5.0
Codename: Juno


lsb_release -a -u
```

returns

```
Distributor id: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic
```

Please help.
Thanks

**edit 1:** It appears that AppCenter also fails fetching updates now. Message is the same.

Answer (score 2):

try removing the ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:elementary-os/stable
```

and then add it again, that way you'll get the key again

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
```

--

this is the repo's url

https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/stable

--

if the command add-apt-repository is missing, you need to install software-properties-common

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

Answer (score 0):

Its still broken over on my system and yes I tried removing and re-adding the repository it didn't seem to do much to fix the problem.

My best guess after digging around the elementary OS Beta StackExchange is to replace the sources with bionic instead of juno to fix the issue through some sort of way I can't find yet.